# Is it possible to copy a land with Mimic Vat that is turned into creature by an enchantment?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I am considering creating a deck which utilizes a strange combo if it can be done.  It uses [Mimic Vat](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Mimic%20Vat) in combination with [Awaken the Ancient](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Awaken%20the%20Ancient).

I want to make it so that when my land, which is a 7/7 giant with haste (that's still a land), is sent to the graveyard I can copy it with Mimic Vat's imprint ability.

- Is it possible to do this? ([Awaken the Ancient](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Awaken%20the%20Ancient)'s is sent to the graveyard separately, and it's ability is what is making the Mountain a creature?
- When Mimic Vat creates the token copy, will it be a 7/7?

Comment: Ok, so you manage to spawn token Mountains (not 7/7s) for 3 mana? How is that useful?

Comment: That was the question: whether or not the tokens would be creatures.  Adding a snarky "how is that useful" is not appreciated.

Comment: That being your question wasn't clear to me at first either. I thought you were asking whether you could still put the Mountain on Mimic Vat, even though putting it in the graveyard would remove the enchantment.

Comment: @murgatroid99, fixed. It wasn't clear to me either. I Upvoted your answer, but you might want to add in the 7/7 part.

Comment: Looking at my original question now, I see what everyone was confused about. Thank you for fixing it @user1873.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When a non-creature card such as a land is put into a graveyard from play and it is a creature when it dies, you **can** use Mimic Vat to exile it, and create tokens later.

When you do this, you will create tokens of the **card** that was exiled, Mountain, *not* the creature that it was when it died.

One of the rulings on the Gatherer page says:

> You may exile a noncreature card with Mimic Vat's first ability. For example, if a nontoken artifact that's become a creature is put into a graveyard from the battlefield, Mimic Vat's first ability triggers and you may exile that card.

With regards to whether the triggered ability will still trigger, even though Awaken the Ancient stops enchanting the Mountain when it dies, [rule 603.6d](http://wiki.mtgsalvation.com/article/Triggered_ability) says

> Leaves-the-battlefield abilities... will trigger based on their existence, and the appearance of objects, prior to the event rather than afterward.

This means that since the Mountain was still a creature *before* it left the battlefield (and caused the Aura to become unattached), it does trigger Mimic Vat.

Answer (score 2):

If a nontoken land that somehow became a creature starts heading to the graveyard, Mimic Vat's first ability triggers and you may choose to exile that card.

You may activate Mimic Vat's second ability to put out a copy of a mountain that you exiled. The result will be a Mountain with haste. The Mountain may have been a 7/7 in a previous life, but **Cards that change zones forget they ever existed anywhere else.**

And not that it makes a difference, but type-changing effects are not copiable anyway.

> 706.2. ... Other effects (including type-changing and text-changing effects), status, and counters are not copied.

Comment: Thank you for answering that. I've been looking for a rule like that for some time, but couldn't find it because it was hard to word it correctly.

Comment: Rule 706.2 does not actually matter in this situation. The mountain you exiled has no type-changing effects to begin with, because it became a plain old Mountain as soon as it went into exile.